# css transition doesn't work like it should in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, opacity

Im making [a photogallery](http://www.sipri.dk/ma/galleri.php), and it works nice in all browsers but Firefox!

In all other browsers but Firefox the page looks like it should, but in firefox it's like the transition effect in CSS on the little examples of the images doesnt work!
I does something weird with opacity..

In the CSS for the little examples of the image, I have an opacity set to `0` in order for the CSS to animate opacity to `1` to make the examples fade up on page load.

If that opacity `0` is set to `1`, the transition effect works in Firefox, however the animation is not working as it should...

The CSS code I have for animation and transition is exactly the same for Chrome, IE, Safari and Firefox.. Just used `-moz-` for Firefox instead, so I can't figure out why it acts different in different browsers.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: When I use Firefox to look at the page it loads the same way as in Chrome.